# set android app background to picture or live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper, user-defined

I was recently told to convert my flash app over to a tablet. So I only just started coding in the java language.

I am going to have a default picture set as the background. However, if the user wishes they would be able to change the the background to a picture contained on their tablet. So it would change the background at that point and load it at that point when started next time. If they later delete the picture, it would go back to the default.

To top it off, my boss who knows nothing of coding thinks it would be easy for me to "allow those cool live backgrounds in a similar fashion" ... As if learning a new programming language was not difficult enough...

Any help or pointing to various tutorials/resources that I would have to merge to effectuate this would be greatly appreciated

Jc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For live wallpapers, you can only show the current live wallpaper that the user has global selected for the device (or static wallpaper if that is what they selected).  This is done by setting the theme of your activity to Theme.Wallpaper.  For example, in onCreate() do Activity.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper) or doing in your manifest

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Would it be possible to find a way to duplicate a live wallpaper into a movieclip or something for the background?
Or to temporarily change the live wallpaper in the background on startup to what was selected, and change it back to its previous setting on exit?

Comment: Sorry no to both.  Third party applications can't change the current live wallpaper directly.